# How can I derive the First Bianchi Identity of the Riemann Tensor from this particular consideration.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, special-relativity

I have been asked to consider the antisymmeterisation:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{[\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\omega_{\lambda]}.
\end{equation}

By expanding out this expression, I have found:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{[\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\omega_{\lambda]} = -\frac{\omega^\sigma}{6}R_{\sigma[\lambda\mu\nu]}.
\end{equation}
I believe I would like for the left hand side to vanish to conclude the First Bianchi Identity:
\begin{equation}
R_{\sigma[\lambda\mu\nu]} = 0,
\end{equation}
although I do not know what to do from here.

Edit: I have been asked to show the details of how I obtained the second equation:

I expanded out the expression as follows:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{[\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\omega_{\lambda]} = \frac{1}{3}(\nabla_\mu\nabla_{[\nu}\omega_{\lambda]} + \nabla_\nu\nabla_{[\lambda}\omega_{\mu]} + \nabla_\lambda\nabla_{[\mu}\omega_{\nu]})
\end{equation}

Expanding this further I got:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{[\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\omega_{\lambda]} = \frac{1}{6}(\nabla_\mu\nabla_{\nu}\omega_{\lambda} - \nabla_\mu\nabla_{\lambda}\omega_{\nu} + \nabla_\nu\nabla_{\lambda}\omega_{\mu}- \nabla_\nu\nabla_{\mu}\omega_{\lambda} +\nabla_\lambda\nabla_{\mu}\omega_{\nu} -\nabla_\lambda\nabla_{\nu}\omega_{\mu})
\end{equation}
Using the identity
\begin{equation}
[\nabla_\alpha,\nabla_\beta]\omega_{\delta} = -R^{\sigma}_{\delta\alpha\beta}\omega_\sigma = -R_{\sigma\delta\alpha\beta}\omega^\sigma 
\end{equation}
I got:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{[\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\omega_{\lambda]} = -\frac{1}{6}(R_{\sigma\lambda\mu\nu}\omega^\sigma + R_{\sigma\nu\lambda\mu}\omega^\sigma + R_{\sigma\mu\nu\lambda}\omega^\sigma) = -\frac{\omega^\sigma}{6}R_{\sigma[\lambda\mu\nu]}
\end{equation}

Comment: Could you provide the details of how you got the second displayed equation?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question showing you how I got to the second displayed equation

Comment: Thanks. @AndreasCap’s answer is the right one, but you can also it see directly from your expanded calculation.

Comment: Hi, It is not quite clear to me how you can see it directly from the expanded calculation, I'm sorry

Comment: As @AndreasCap observes, the key point is that the Levi-Civita connection is torsion-free. This means that $\nabla_\alpha\omega_\beta = \nabla_\beta\omega_\alpha$. The first two terms on the right side of the equation after "Expanding this further..." are $$\nabla_\mu\nabla_{\nu}\omega_{\lambda} - \nabla_\mu\nabla_{\lambda}\omega_{\nu} = \nabla_\mu(\nabla_\nu\omega_\lambda - \nabla_\lambda\omega_\nu) = 0.$$ The remaining 4 terms vanish for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

The argument why $\nabla_{[\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\omega_{\lambda]}=0$ is as follows: As you have implicitly noted in your computations, you can alternate the inner derivative first. But then torsion-freeness of the Levi-Civita connection implies that $\nabla_{[\nu}\omega_{\lambda]}=(d\omega)_{\nu\lambda}$. For the same reason you get $\nabla_{[\mu}(d\omega)_{\nu\lambda]}=d(d\omega)_{\mu\nu\lambda}=0$. So the main ingredient is $d^2=0$.